# CSS Set new border value on mouse hover

Tags: css

I have a list , then I set its css to :

```
.dropdown-menu > li {
   list-style: none outside none;
   height: 22px;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #e1e1e1;
   width: 178px;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Then when mouse hover :

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover{
   color: #EC5B00 !important;
   z-index: 3;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color:#dddddd #ffffff #dddddd #dddddd;
   border-width: 1px 3px 1px 0px;
   width: 183px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   margin-left: 1px;
}
```

**Problem** :

Even I set the border to solid style, but the dotted still exists, so there're two lines (one is a dotted, and another one is solid). How to omit the dotted one on mouse hover by css?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you..

**Update** :

After changing the style by all the answers, then I found one problem, one more `dotted` border is getting from the other `li` next to the current hover `li`, here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/gbw3fj14/

Comment: dotted border is for `li` element

Comment: `.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover` to `.dropdown-menu > li:hover`

Answer (score 0):

The `border-bottom: 1px dotted #e1e1e1;` style is set to `li`, you are changing the `a` border later, try to change your selector from `li > a:hover` to `li:hover`

```
.dropdown-menu > li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #e1e1e1;
    width: 178px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li:hover {
    color: #EC5B00 !important;
    z-index: 3;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#dddddd #ffffff #dddddd #dddddd;
    border-width: 1px 3px 1px 0px;
    width: 183px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e0nod8dj/)**.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/

your wrote wrong 
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover to .dropdown-menu > li:hover

Comment: Kindly have a look on my updated question with the jsFiddle, thanks.